# deleting row given specific interval

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

i have the following problem given the following construction of a

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


# shift+alt+e FOR IKKE at køre hele programmet hver gang
tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'XOM']
start_date = datetime.date(2010, 1, 2)
end_date = datetime.date(2020, 12, 31)
daily_data = yf.download(tickers, start=start_date, end=end_date)
daily_data = daily_data['Adj Close'].dropna()
len_months = [v for _, v in daily_data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))]
len_months = len(len_months)
df = daily_data
df["DateTime"] = df.index
df["DateTime"] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime']).dt.date
frames = []
months_forward = 12
for i in range(len_months - (hvor_mange_måneder_frem - 1)):
    a = df[(df["DateTime"] < start_date + relativedelta(months=i + hvor_mange_måneder_frem)) & (df["DateTime"] >= start_date + relativedelta(months=i))]
    frames.append(a[tickers])
```

given the above iteration I want either to remove all values from the start of the dataframe df to the maximum date of a or if its easier i want to access the month which comes right after each iteration of a, meaning the first iteration I want to access all data in January 2011, nest iteration February  2011 etc. if the data is removed the "newdf", should each iteration be smaller and smaller. I believe my following code removes the subdataframe a, but i also need to remove all data before the max date of a

```
for w in frames:
    newdf = df.drop(w.index)
    newdf = newdf.drop(columns='DateTime')
    # analyse
    new_frames = [v for _, v in newdf.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))]  # opdeler data i måneder
    print(new_frames)
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: May you provide some example data?

Comment: the exmaple or data i want do do i on is the daily_data